# How to edit the back button (not left button) on navigation bar for the present view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Since left button is a different thing, and like back bar button it doesn't help in navigation to the last page it is coming from, I am not interested in using it. However I want to edit the back button such that it removes default the back indicator image (arrow) and have text value- "Cancel" and it navigates it to the last page it is coming from.

I have tried few things. Some of them reflects in all of the pages in the app unfortunately and not just on the current page. Some don't work at all (needless to say)

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question has two parts:

1. Changing the text of the back item
2. Changing the back indicator image

### Changing the Title

The back item of a view controller actually belongs to the **previous** view controller. You can change this in the previous controller's code (ie. the controller you are coming from) with the following code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    backItem.title = "Cancel" // Change to whatever you want
    backItem.tintColor = UIColor.red // The color of the text can be changed too if you want
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem // Will show in the next view controller being pushed
}
```

### Changing the Back Indicator Image

Changing the title as seen above only changes the text ("cancel" in your case), but does **not** actually change the indicator icon or image. To do this, go into the class for the view controller you are trying to change.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // "image" is file you want
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "image")
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "image")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a base navigation controller, you can edit image, text color and font in this way.

```
class BaseNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: color,
            NSAttributedStringKey.font: font
        ]
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = color

        if #available(iOS 11, *) {
            self.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = image
            self.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = image
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancel))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton
}

@objc func cancel(){
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

you can also initialize the UIBarButtonItem with a custom image, and you can also do this in the storyboard you don't have to necessarily use code.

Comment: Please read the title of the answer, the OP clearly states that he is not interested using the `leftBarButtonItem`